# unifiedpush-node-sender completion block not triggered

Tags: node.js, push-notification, openshift, aerogear

I used Node Sender API for the AeroGear Unified Push server for the 1.1.x series of the UnifiedPush Server.   It can be found [here](https://aerogear.org/docs/specs/aerogear-unifiedpush-nodejs-client/).   It sent fine.   Client received fine.  But the logs below did not occur at all.

Any suggestions?

```
  agSender(settings).then((client) => {
    client.sender.send(message, options).then((response) => {
      console.log('send succeeded');
      console.log('send notification success', response);
    });
  });
```

Edit:  After update node.js on my Mac to the latest version, now there is this message in the console.  It still works fine.  But I do need the completion block to work so I can trigger another sequence of events.

```
(node:4202) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: UPS request returned status code: 202
```

Edit 2nd time: If I temporarily disable this code in sender.js, then the completion block gets called.  What is status code 202?

```
        // if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        //     return reject(
        //         new Error(`UPS request returned status code: ${response.statusCode}`)
        //     );
        // }
```

Comment: what is the version of the sender are you using?  Also could you put a ".catch" at the end of the send to see if it is returning an error

Comment: @lholmquist:  The current version the link above, I think it is 0.14.0

Comment: @lholmquist:  Please see my edit.

Comment: Looks like you found a Bug.  Achievement unlocked!!  I'll update this and put out a new 0.14.1 release soon.   202 is accepted,  and is defined in the API for the Push server,  https://aerogear.org/docs/specs/aerogear-unifiedpush-rest/index.html#397083935

Comment: Version 0.14.1 should be live now.

Comment: @lholmquist: Achievement reward: Rapid 0.14.1 release!  Not bad at all.  Thank you.